# Convert Bigquery results to Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

Below is the code to convert BigQuery results into Pandas data frame.
Im learning Python&Pandas and wonder if i can get suggestion/ideas about any kind of improvements to the code?

```
#...code to run query, that returns 3 columns: 'date' DATE, 'currency' STRING,'rate' FLOAT...

rows, total_count, token = query.fetch_data()
currency = []
rate = []
dates = []
for row in rows:
    dates.append(row[0])
    currency.append(row[1])
    rate.append(row[2])


dict = {
'currency' : currency,
'date' : dates,
'rate' : rate
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict)

df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
df2 = df2.set_index('date')
```

The above works. But looks chunky. Is there any way to do the same thing more efficiently than the above?
I tried libraries such as sqlalchemy but they do not support BigQuery. And generally my question is about code and syntax above.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `read_gbq()` instead: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_gbq.html

Answer (score 12):

As of 23rd March 2023,

You can directly convert BigQuery results to pandas dataframe with one go! (Using offical Google Cloud provided python library)

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd

client = bigquery.Client()

sql = """
    SELECT name, SUM(number) as count
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY count DESC
    LIMIT 10
"""

df = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()
```

Reference :
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-results-dataframe

Comment: I had to pip install db-dtypes first. Once that was installed, this solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

Per the [Using BigQuery with Pandas](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage/pandas.html) page in the Google Cloud Client Library for Python:

> As of version 0.29.0, you can use the to_dataframe() function to retrieve query results or table rows as a pandas.DataFrame.

Aside: See [Migrating from pandas-gbq](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration) for the difference between the `google-cloud-bigquery` BQ Python client library and `pandas-gbq`.