# SQL query results to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have the results from a query obtained through Python:

```
<google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator object at 0x00000289E881C670>
```

I'd like to convert them to a pandas Dataframe.

I'm trying things like `df = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)`, but I don't have the `connection`.

My code to get the query results is

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Load BigQuery credentials
credentials_json_file = r"credentials.json"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credentials_json_file)
project_id = "idi-rewan"
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project_id)

# Define query
query_string = """
   SELECT * FROM `database.table`
   """
query_job = client.query(query_string)

results = query_job.result()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pandas-gbq package and use the read_gbq function as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647310/convert-bigquery-results-to-pandas-data-frame) post.

The read_gbq function takes the SQL string as argument and the different credentials for the authentication.